# scrape javascript submitaction

Tags: javascript, scrapy, web-crawler

I was try to scrape course info with scrapy, but when I click on individual course numbers it does not redirect me to another url, but a javascript document action call. How can I access the javascript document in the href and scrape them individually like I would on a normal html using scrapy?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the site url?

Comment: https://home.cunyfirst.cuny.edu/psp/cnyepprd/GUEST/HRMS/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.HC_CLASS_SEARCH_GBL&IsFolder=false&IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%252cIsFolder . and the query should be using Kingsborough CC, fall term 2018 and BIO department. Thanks!

Comment: I took a look, in this function JS it makes a POST request, the second value is one of the parameters that it uses. The URL of request is: https://hrsa.cunyfirst.cuny.edu/psc/cnyhcprd/GUEST/HRMS/c/COMMUNITY_ACCESS.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL